# A problem about Klingenberg's lemma

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I see the particular of Klingenberg's lemma:

> If $M$ is compact and the sectional curvature
> $$
> K\le \delta
> $$
> then, the  injective radius $\text{inj}(M)$ satisfy
> $$
> \text{inj}(M) \ge \min\{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt \delta}, \frac{l(M)}{2}\}
> $$
> where $l(M)$ is the length of the shortest simple closed geodesic in $M$.

Since $M$ is compact, if $M$ is smooth, I feel (just feel, not sure) there is a  closed geodesic $\gamma$ in $M$ such that
$$
l(\gamma) =l(M).
$$
Then, for any $p\in \gamma$, I have
$$
\exp_p:T_pM\rightarrow M
$$
is  injective on $B_0(\frac{l(\gamma)}{2})\subset T_pM$. $B_0(\frac{l(\gamma)}{2})$ is the open ball center at origin and radius is $\frac{l(\gamma)}{2}$. Therefore, I have
$$
\text{inj}(M) \le \frac{l(M)}{2}   \tag{1}
$$
Obviously, it is incompatible with Klingenberg's lemma. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your inequality is reversed. The injectivity radius is at most half the length of the shortest closed geodesic, not at least.

Comment: @Deane  Do you mean (1) is reversed ?   Sorry for my poor English. I think ‘The injectivity radius is at most half the length of the shortest closed geodesic’   equal to $inj(M) \le \frac{l(M)}{2}$.

Comment: I believe the correct inequality is $$
(M) \le \min\{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt \delta}, \frac{l(M)}{2}\}
$$